# Possible to pass `docker build` flags via docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

- I have a Dockerfile `Dockerfile.foo`
- I run `Dockerfile.foo` using `docker run -p 8000:8000 --cap-add=IPC_LOCK johndoe/repo:latest`

Everything works fine so far.

My issue is, `--cap-add=IPC_LOCK` is required to run `Dockerfile.foo` (no way around that, that I'm aware of).

However, I'd like to run `Dockerfile.foo` as a part of my `dockercompose.yaml`, because I have a few other services that use the container produced by `Dockerfile.foo`. Issue is, I can't figure out how to (1) either use the `johndoe/repo:latest` image, or (2) Use `Dockerfile.foo` in `dockercompose.yaml` *and* pass that `--cap-add=IPC_LOCK` flag to either the image or the Dockerfile (depending on whichever I'm allowed to use).

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If not, is there a suggested/recommended way to attain my objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`cap_add`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cap_add) clause in your docker compose file:

```yaml
cap_add:
  - IPC_LOCK
```

So your `dockercompose.yaml` would look something like:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  johndoe:
    build: /path/to/dir
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
```

When you run `docker compose up`, the `johndoe` service will use an image built from the Dockerfile and run the container with the the `--cap-add` flag.

Also note that Dockerfile has no extension.

Comment: An open and shut case, thanks @viggnah